# How To Write A Bat File That Will Open CMD And Perform Multiple Commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a bat file command that will run cmd and for example, make a new user and elevate the user to administrator privileges.

**Or Even Better!** Write a bat command to open run (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), write a command to open cmd and then type out the command, `net user --- --- /add` etc....

Many thanks to whoever can help, this is where I am so far:

`start cmd.exe /k "net user smith admin /add" pause 0.5 /c "net user administrators smith /add"`

starting run did work, but I could not use `/c` or `/k` to write a command, I tried write but I had no clue what it actually did.

Comment: Batch scripts are (essentially) just a list of commands to run in the command prompt. Just stick the commands you want in a text file and save it with the extension .bat and you should be good to go; no reason to call `cmd.exe` at all! (Also, `pause` only accepts whole numbers.)

Comment: Would it not be `net user /add smith admin` and `net localgroup administrators smith /add`

Answer (score 1):

Try creating batch file named AddUser.cmd with following:

```
@echo off
net user %1 admin /add
net user Administrators %1 /add
```

Then run it like this:

```
   AddUser smith
```

The %1 in your batch file is replaced by the first parameter you call it with.

You can verify first parameter is provided like this:

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" goto :Syntax

net user %1 admin /add
net user Administrators %1 /add
goto :End

:Syntax
echo Syntax: AddUser [userid]
goto :End

:End
```